# Sourcing an external array for jquery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, file, autocomplete

I have a very large array (1500 in length) that I'd like to use as the source for jquery autocomplete on an input field I have.  Because the array is so large, I've moved it to another file and was hoping to source it but I'm having trouble finding a straight forward way to do this.

Here's an example of the file with the array, I'm not even sure what file format this should be.  My app in in flask but I'm using jquery in my templates so perhaps `array.js`:

```
['entry1, 'entry', 'entry1']
```

Then my autocomplete:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: array.js
        });
     } );
</script>
```

Is there a simple way to do this?  I'm not so familiar with jquery and javascript

Answer (score 0):

So I answered my own question:

You need to make the array file into a js file like `array.js` and edit it set the array to a variable like:

```
let array = ['entry1, 'entry', 'entry1']
```

Then in the script import the array.js by doing:

```
<script src = "/static/array.js"></script>
<script>
   $( function() {
       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
         source: array
        });
    } );
</script>
```